# Change button styles PayPal express

Tags: paypal

Can I specify custom CSS settings for the Express Checkout button, or can I only use the standard styles(shape, label, size, etc)?

Comment: Provide code which you have tried

Answer (score 0):

Although this is beyond PayPal's coverage of changing existing code style, you are able to do that by your own CSS skills.

Comment: How can I add css styles to an element from Iframe?